# Web Hosting vs cloud hosting - things to do

Tags: url, google-cloud-platform, cloud, apache-phoenix

I am new to this, hence asking.

I am trying to host an e-commerce website myself having 2 components -
1. e-commerce customer facing site made in Angular.
2. e-commerce Admin module site (with back end DB in PostgreSQL) made in Phoenix framework with Elixir.

I have already registered a domain name from Domain.com. Now I need few clarifications as crisp as possible to clear my confusions.

1. Domain.com is asking me to purchase a basic hosting service from them which costs $45. Otherwise they are keeping the "Park" and "Home" pointer types deactivated and I can't add directory there.

[image: Pointers and SubDomain settings page of Domain.com]

Do I need to activate it if I plan to host my sites in cloud? Personally I don't want to purchase it since I am planning to host my site in either Google Cloud Platform or AZURE. If I don't purchase, then how can I point my domain name (xyz.com) to the e-commerce site hosted in separate cloud?

The question might be silly, but I really need to understand it.

2. How does the other options like "Subdirectory", "URL Standard" and "URL Stealth" work? Can they help me to point to my site in cloud?
3. What should be my next steps to host the sites in cloud in a cheapest possible way? Is there any further costs involved, if so what are they?

Lastly do I get a new url when I host my 2 sites in cloud? If so, how can I set it up in Domain.com?

An elaborate answer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a link for deploying Angular in GCP.

https://medium.com/@asanoop24/deploying-angular-6-app-on-google-app-engine-b6259d4c16c2

Found a link for deploying Phoenix in GCP.

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-google-compute-engine

Yet to find some other cheaper and better alternatives to host 2 sites (angular e-commerce and elixir admin app)in Domain.com (rather in any other hosting sites)!!